# Estimating parameters of SIR model and problem with real-life data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, logarithms, exponential-function, matlab

I tried to make an SIR model based on real-world data. But, I ran into a snag when I'm trying to estimate the parameters of $\beta$ and $\gamma$. With equations:

$$    
\begin{cases}
      \frac{dS(t)}{dt}=-\beta\frac{S(t)I(t)}{N}\\[6pt]
     \frac{dI(t)}{dt}=\beta\frac{S(t)I(t)}{N}- \gamma I(t) \\[6pt]
      \frac{dR(t)}{dt}=\gamma I(t)
    \end{cases}
$$

So my data that I am using is divided into two the number of infected individuals and recovered individuals. I already tried to get the value of $(\beta - \gamma)$ by integrating the infected differential equation and yield:

$$I = I_0 e^{(\beta - \gamma)t}$$

I then linearize the equation using $ln()$ and do linear regression from my data of daily cases of infected individuals which yields an $m$ = $(\beta - \gamma)$ value of

$$ln(I(t))=(\beta - \gamma)t+ln(I_0)$$

$$m = (\beta - \gamma) =  2.808$$

Then, I estimated the value of $\gamma$ by using:

$$\gamma = \frac{R(t+1) - R(t)}{I(t)}$$

By evaluating the average $\gamma$ from my data I calculated a value of:

$$\gamma = 0.01224$$

Thus, $\beta$ should be

$$\beta = 2.808 + 0.01224 = 2.8202$$

Though when I model in MATLAB with my parameters of initial population $N = 100$ and initial infected $I = 1$, the value is very abnormal, with a simple ODE code:

```
clear all, close all, clc

A = 2.808 + 0.01224965083;
B = 0.01224965083;

tspan = [0:1:300];
y0 = [100 1 0];
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)odefcn(y,A,B),tspan,y0);

figure(1)
hold on
plot(t,y(:,1),'-o')
plot(t,y(:,2),'-*')
plot(t,y(:,3),'-+')

function dydt = odefcn(y,A,B)

    dydt = zeros(3,1);
    dydt(1) = -A*y(2)*y(1);
    dydt(2) = A*y(2)*y(1)-B*y(2);
    dydt(3) = B*y(2);
end
```

**Question**
Why does the value of my susceptible and infected individuals immediately jump to max and min on the very first day, then it exponentially decreases? Is this due to the parameters or is it something else? You can refer to image below.

My reasoning at first would most likely be because of the $\beta$ value is too high, as when I change the $\beta$ value to be smaller than the value of $\gamma$ the graph works it does not jump from min to max but increases and decreases exponentially. But, I don't know why this occur, any ideas?

[image]

Additionally, @user10354138 mentioned that I miss dividing $\beta / N$ but still though there isn't much of a difference. If only jumps to min and max at x = 3 not the first.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you forgot the $N$ in $\beta SI/N$ so it should be `y(2)*y(1)/100` instead of `y(2)*y(1)` in your `dydt(1)` and `dydt(2)`.

Comment: @user10354138 yes true, I also tried that and the the value still jumps significantly while there is a difference where it jumps at x = 3, unlike the image above where it immediately jumps when x = 1. Still though its not the case.

Comment: In fact, I don't believe your equation for $I(t)$.  In order to get $I(t)=I_0\exp((\beta-\gamma)t)$ you need $S(t)=N$ for all $t$ which means there are never any infected individuals.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, thats true, because we are assuming that at the beginning of the pandemic $S(t) = N$, thus why we have the I(t) equation.

Comment: No, $S(t)=N$ only before the pandemic.  Once it starts, you are forced into $S(t)+I(t)+R(t)=N$ instead (assuming nobody dies) so you don't have the simplification afforded by $S(t)=N$.

Comment: @user10354138 I see, then do you have any suggestions on how I could estimate the value of $\beta$ given if I have a real-world stats of daily infected cases? I tried regression but that didn't quite work out. Also since the beginning I am also already quite skeptical as most examples of SIR models always have the $\beta$ and $\gamma$ value less than 1.

Comment: Calculate $S=N-I-R$ and you have $d(I+R)/dt=\beta SI/N$ which allows you to estimate $\beta$.

Comment: So, I would simply integrate the $d(I+R)/dt = \beta SI/N$ yes? and get the average $\beta$ value of each day. Though as an alternative I also found this in the web for discrete data, where $S_{t+1} - S_t = -\beta S_t I_t$ what do you think about this? Because it will be much simpler as I already have the data for each $t$

Comment: See  http://adventuresinpython.blogspot.com/2012/08/fitting-differential-equation-system-to.html on how one can fit data to the zombie apocalypse model. The procedures there have room for improvement in terms of arranging the code, the mathematical side would not change much.